# Mitigating security risks of javascript objects using require.js

Tags: security, requirejs, amd

I'm a little paranoid about storing sensitive information in global variables on the browser; who wouldn't be. Enter AMD! My question is, can we confidently use require.js to completely isolate variables, to help mitigate unwanted manipulation of variables from the console? Has anyone found a backdoor, or maybe a better way to put it is, has anyone witnessed any security issues with the require.js library?
Thanks!

Comment: I'll open Dev Tools, put a breakpoint in the code that has your sensitive values in scope, and read them just fine. Or use Fiddler/Wireshark to capture the data before the browser even sees it. If you send info to the client, he will find a way to read it.

Comment: Not worried about the variables being read, like you said, easy to read on the stack. It's manipulating the variables through the console that I'm concerned about. Also, looking at the data via wireshark is only going to be an issue with plain text, am I right? Network encryption by nature mitigates MIM attacks right? Thanks!

Comment: The variables can still be manipulated in the console when a breakpoint is hit. Why is this a concern? You should be validating all user input on the server anyway...

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. Even if you don't have any global variable the user can still go through your source code and add break points, then when the code reach the breakpoint he can manipulate all the variables that are accessible in the actual scope.

Take a look at this [gamedev question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37392/anti-cheat-javascript-for-browser-html5-game) which has some advices on how to make it harder (but not impossible) for users to cheat your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the attacker can always view the source.

But if you size and shape the payload, minifying and modularize parts/regions of the client, serving them in accordance with use-case narratives on-demand, you effectively add a layer of security that exists due to the assumption of human-play.

A bot cannot simply traverse directories on a server, but instead must (via JavaScript) navigate the application intelligently, only getting code at a uniquely specified point in the app. It must know when certain payloads are essential to the use-case (say offering up credit card info N screens into a process).

Moreover, client code and be obfuscated w/r/t IP address or along continuous, periodic release cycles.